# How remove "(2002)" (without quotes) from string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this

`This is some text; Awesome! (2002)`

I want to remove the "`(2002)`" part from it using Ruby. How is this done? I know in unix it'd be

`sed -e 's/([0-9]*)//g'`

Comment: Would `stringVariable.gsub(/[(\d\d\d\d)]/, "")` do it?

Comment: When asking, we expect to see evidence of your effort. Currently it looks like you didn't try. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove any amount of whitespace symbols followed with a `(`, then one or more digits and a `)` at the end of the string, use a *[`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub)* with a `/\s*\(\d+\)\z/` regex:

```
s = "This is some text; Awesome! (2002)"
s = s.sub(/\s*\(\d+\)\z/,"")              # => This is some text; Awesome!
```

or

```
s[/\s*\(\d+\)\z/] = ""                    # => This is some text; Awesome!
```

See [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/N1BCjM)

If you mean a literal `2002`, use it instead of `\d+`.

**NOTE**: When you use `s[...] = ""` approach, you still get a string as the return type, you can check it with `s.class`.

**NOTE2**: If you need to obtain the `2002` value separately, use `s[/\s*\((\d+)\)\z/, 1]` where `1` is passed to the matching method to return the contents of Group 1 only.

**NOTE3**: To split the string at the last space and get the `["This is some text; Awesome!", "2002"]` as a result, use either Cary's suggestion with the regex containing a capturing group around `\d+` - `[s.sub(/\s*\((\d+)\)\z/,''), $1]` (as `$1` variable will hold the capture group 1 contents after `sub` executes), or `s.split(/\s*\((\d+)\)\z/)` where the result holds the substring from the start up to our pattern, and the digits that are wrapped with a `(...)` capturing group (after splitting, these values are placed into the result, not discarded).

And finally, `/\([^)]*\)/` matches anything inside `(...)` (`\(` matches an open parenthesis, `[^)]*` matches 0 or more chars other than `)` and `\)` matches a closing parenthesis).

Comment: Can I capture the date "`2002`" in the same process?

Comment: You may capture the digits with the help of the capturing group. See [`\s*\((\d+)\)\z`](http://rubular.com/r/XfaoT9yV6J) regex demo. Then, you can access it using `Regexp.last_match.captures.first`. See [this Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/18OqLb).

Comment: So `stringVariable.match(/\s*\((\d+)\)\z/)` would return the string `2002`?

Comment: No, [`stringVariable[/\s*\((\d+)\)\z/, 1]`](http://ideone.com/xh9pu8) will (`1` is passed to the matching method to return the contents of Group 1 only).

Comment: Would `\(*\)` get anything in parentheses generally?

Comment: No, anything in parentheses: `\([^)]*\)` - *a `(`, followed with zero or more chars other than `)` up to a `)`*.

Comment: You can study the syntax at [`geoffgarside/oniguruma`](https://github.com/geoffgarside/oniguruma/blob/master/Syntax.txt), and test your regexps at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/). Also, check the [*Using Regular Expressions with Ruby*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) page.

Comment: I see so `\:` would match `:`?

Comment: Yes, but you do not have to escape a colon in a Ruby regex pattern, it is not a special regex metacharacter. Try and you will see.

Comment: If you want both the resulting string and `2002`, you could write `[str.sub(/\((\d+)\)/,''), $1] #=> ["This is some text; Awesome! ", "2002"]`.

Answer (score 3):

If I wanted to remove something, I'd use:

```
foo = 'This is some text; Awesome! (2002)'
foo['(2002)'] = ''
foo # => "This is some text; Awesome! "
```

You can also use regex instead of the fixed string. Either way, assigning `''` to the match will remove it.

```
foo[/\(2002\)/] = ''
foo # => "This is some text; Awesome! "
```

or:

```
foo[/\(\d+\)/] = ''
foo # => "This is some text; Awesome! "
```

This is documented in String's [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method.

Comment: Is there something similar to PHP's `trim` in Ruby?

Comment: Is `foo` still a string or is it now an array after you apply `foo['(2002)'] = ''`?

Comment: What does trying have to do with knowing the datatype? I mean, for all I know strings and arrays are the same kind of object in Ruby. I don't know...

Comment: Trying is an essential characteristic of developers who are serious about learning; We dig in and teach ourselves, often by using IRB. Ruby's `String.[]` documentation, which is a simple hop away, also makes it easy to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The regex I showed you on a different question can be modified for use here:

```
str = "something (capture) something (capture2)"
regex = /(\(\w+\))‌​/
str.scan(regex).flatten(1) # => ["(capture)", "(capture2)"]
```

The only change is the addition of `\(` and `\)` in the match group.

You can plug this regex into `gsub` to remove all matches:

```
str.gsub(regex, "")
# => "something  something "
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the string.